# Angular 2 how to import libraries in node_modules?

Tags: angular

I've been trying to import node_modules libraries into my app but the console keeps on returning

```
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
```

not found. Does any know how to fix this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PrcApplication</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please tell us the folder structure of both `index.html` and `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below under HTML Header and try:

```
  <base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `script` tag will cause an ajax call to that path, which is not what you want because in production, your node_modules folder is not available, and there is only dist folder to be available.

In these cases, you'd need to import that particular file inside one of your own js/ts files so the file would be imported and packed together with your src files.

I don't know what you're using for bundling or rather even you have bundling or not, but you can import it in your app.module.ts or somewhere similar.

Normally there is a file called vendor.ts or pollyfill.ts which is designed for these things.